# Return only one row from duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am accessing a database with names tied to companies. Names are unique in the table. There can be multiple people that have the same company. I need to return only ONCE instance of the company if is duplicate, so that I can display the information according to company. My code is as follows:

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM vendoreducation WHERE company LIKE "TestCompany" GROUP BY company');
```

That obviously doesnt work, and I dont want to specify individual companies. I just want to be able to return a list of all of the companys in the DB. If there are multiple entries that have the same company name, just return one of those.

**EDIT**
The answer I chose was in the right direction, but the answer that I ended up going with was `m.buettner`'s answer.

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`

Comment: or LIMIT 1 will stop at the first match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vendoreducation WHERE company LIKE "TestCompany"');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would ask for clarification in a comment, but I am lacking the rep, sorry. If you only need one row per company, does it even matter what the other columns are? Or do you really just want to find out a list of all companies?

For the latter, this should do:

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT DISTINCT company FROM vendoreducation;');
```

Of course, you could also include any columns that will be identical for all rows of the same company. However, since some columns will probably have values that differ (like the names you mentioned), using `DISTINCT` with `*` will probably just give you all rows again.

**EDIT:** If you DO want one full row per company you could simply use the list of all companies retrieved by the line above and then query one row for every single company, by using the `LIMIT 1` solution with every individual company in turn. But maybe then you should think about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) anyway if that is an option at all (i.e. if you can alter the database).

Comment: I should have clarified more before I accepted the other answer, as what you said is eventually have I have done... I accepted the other prematurely because it covered the premise of what I needed.

Comment: Never mind, things happen way too fast here ^^. However, if this is what you were actually looking for you could still spare an upvote to bring to people's attention who find this question while having the same problem ;) ... EDIT: You could also still edit that clarification into your question for people who will find this later.

Answer (score 0):

`$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM vendoreducation WHERE company LIKE "TestCompany" GROUP BY company LIMIT 1');`

OR

`$result = $pdo->query('SELECT distinct * FROM vendoreducation WHERE company LIKE "TestCompany" GROUP BY company');`